# String comparison in Databricks Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks, instr

```
select distinct
 promo_name 
  ,case 
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P0"),2)  = "P0"   then 0
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P1"),2)  = "P1"   then 1
    When substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P01"),3) = "P01"  then 1
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P2"),2)  = "P2"   then 2 
    When substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P02"),3) = "P02"  then 2  
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P3"),2)  = "P3"   then 3 
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P03"),3) = "P03"  then 3
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P4"),2)  = "P4"   then 4  
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P04"),3) = "P04"  then 4 
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P5"),2)  = "P5"   then 5
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P05"),3) = "P05"  then 5
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P6"),2)  = "P6"   then 6
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P06"),3) = "P06"  then 6
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P7"),2)  = "P7"   then 7
    when substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P07"),3) = "P07"  then 7 
    when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P8"),2))  ="P8"  then 8 
    when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P08"),3)) ="P08" then 8
    when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P9"),2))  ="P9"  then 9
    when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P09"),3)) ="P09" then 9
    when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P10"),3)) ="P10" then 10 
    when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P11"),3)) ="P11" then 11
    when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P12"),3)) ="P12" then 12
```

else 0 end as promo_id
,Case
when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P10"),3)) = "P10" then 10
when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P11"),3)) = "P11" then 11
when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P12"),3)) = "P12" then 12
when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P13"),3)) = "P13" then 13
when trim(substring(promo_name,instr(promo_name, "P14"),3)) = "P14" then 14
else 0 end as id
from hbi_dns_protected.store_zones_stock_v7_1_4
where promo_name is not null

Trying to extract ID from String, it works fine from P10 to P14 when I use in a separate column, when I do in the same column it just pick 1 instead of 11, 1 instead of 12 etc...

Am I making an mistake here?
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FWnY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `regexp_extract` to do a RegEx extraction from your string, rather than write code for each case, something like:

```
%sql
SELECT *,
  regexp_extract( promo_name, ' P(\\d+)', 1 ) AS promoNumber
FROM tmp
```

My results:

[image: My results]

NB The regex is case-sensitive.  If you have a requirement to capture either lower or upper case Ps, then you could use a character class ie `[pP]` instead.

A full explanation of the RegEx pattern used:

1. the regex starts off with a space character and a capital P.  This will match literally a space and a capital P.  If you want to make the match case-insensitive, you can use a character class eg `[pP]` which says match any character (case-sensitive) in the brackets
2. The next component of the RegEx is `(\\d+)`.  This is made up of the RegEx pattern `\d` for matching digits, the `+` symbol which means, 'match one or more'.  The brackets make it into a group, which is group 1.  The `\d` has an additional slash which is an escape character required for the Spark SQL implementation of `regexp_extract`.
3. the last argument of `regexp_extract` has the value of 1 which means 'return group 1 from the function'

I use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for testing and practicing with RegEx expressions.

Comment: thank you for your reply, Actually i have a long string more than 255 charachters sometime where P1, P01 and so on, position of p1, p01, p02 is not consistent in string, that is why i was using instr function to find the position and get the number, how can i do in regular expression

Comment: Can you provide some more realistic sample data and expected results then please?

Comment: sure will load in a minute

Comment: How can attach sample data file here?

Comment: added sample data, please click on sample data link above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032002/regular-expression-to-find-specific-character-in-a-string

Comment: wBob, is it possible if you can explain the logic of regular expression here for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

The code stops at the first match, so "11" matches "1".

I would suggest reordering and using `like`:

```
(case when promo_name like 'P14%' then 14
      when promo_name like 'P13%' then 13
      . . .
 end)
```

Perhaps you should ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.  There might be a simpler approach.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, Why it works individually? P14 , p13 position is not consistent it that is why I am using instr function to find the position, shall I use Like operation in case statement

Comment: As you can see in image i have attached, it is working fine in other column but not in same column, as per you suggestion tried like operator as well

Comment: @user3061338 . . . The `case` expression stops at the first match.  So, "P1" matches "P11". If "P1" is in an earlier `case` comparison, then you never see the match for "P11".