# Regular expression to find Specific character in a string

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have these sample values

```
prm_2020 P02 United Kingdom London 2 for 2
prm_2020 P2 United Kingdom London 2 for 2
prm_2020 P10 United Kingdom London 2 for 2
prm_2020 P11 United Kingdom London 2 for 2
```

Need to find P2, P02, P11,p06,p05 like this, trying to use Regexp_extract function in databricks. struggling to find the correct expression. Once i find P10, p6 from string i need to put numbers in new column called ID

```
select distinct
    promo_name
   ,regexp_extract(promo_name, '(?<=p\d+\s+)P\d+') as regexp_id
from stock
where promo_name is not null


select distinct
    promo_name
   ,regexp_extract(promo_name, 'P[0-9]+') as regexp_id
from stock
where promo_name is not null
```

both generating errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017975/string-comparison-in-databricks-spark-sql/63024352#63024352

Answer (score 0):

The expression would be:

```
select regexp_extract(col, 'P[0-9]+')
```

Comment: Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 179.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3 in stage 179.0 (TID 12754, 10.92.191.203, executor 23): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1

Comment: you should probably deal with strings that will return no match in your select statement, by using some sort of IF NULL construct.

Comment: thanks veverke, there is no null value in my column as it has already been filtered

Comment: @user3061338 . . . I do not see how a `regexp_extract()` could cause an out-of-bounds error.  Something else seems to be going on.

Answer (score 0):

One regex could be `(?<=prm_\d+\s+)P\d+`
Besides searching for strings in the form of P* where * is a digit, it also checks that such strings are preceded by strings in the form prm_* where * is a digit.

Keep in mind case sensitivity. The solution above IS case sensitive (if your input comes as PRM, then your match will be discarded.) I am not familiar with apache-spark but I assume it supports parameters such as /i as other platforms to indicate the regex should be case insensitive.

[Regexr.com demo](http://regexr.com/58sfh)

Answer (score 0):

Just select the group 0

```
regexp_extract(promo_name, 'P[0-9]+',0)
```

Answer (score 0):

function `regexp_extract` will take 3 parameters.

- Column value
- Regex Pattern
- Group Index

```
def regexp_extract(e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp: String,groupIdx: Int): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

You are missing last parameter in `regexp_extract` function.

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------+
|data                                      |
+------------------------------------------+
|prm_2020 P02 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|
|prm_2020 P2 United Kingdom London 2 for 2 |
|prm_2020 P10 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|
|prm_2020 P11 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|
+------------------------------------------+
```

```
df
.withColumn("parsed_data",regexp_extract(col("data"),"(P[0-9]*)",0))
.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
|data                                      |parsed_data|
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
|prm_2020 P02 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|P02        |
|prm_2020 P2 United Kingdom London 2 for 2 |P2         |
|prm_2020 P10 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|P10        |
|prm_2020 P11 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|P11        |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

```
df.createTempView("tbl")
spark
.sql("select data,regexp_extract(data,'(P[0-9]*)',0) as parsed_data from tbl")
.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
|data                                      |parsed_data|
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
|prm_2020 P02 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|P02        |
|prm_2020 P2 United Kingdom London 2 for 2 |P2         |
|prm_2020 P10 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|P10        |
|prm_2020 P11 United Kingdom London 2 for 2|P11        |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+
```